# Listening to burned CD's

Tags: halacha

I have a throwback question from the early 2000's but that became relevant recently, which I'm asking for a friend.

If a person were to discover burned (digitally copied)CD's which almost certainly were generated from websites like Napster, Limewire, etc in his position, could he/she listen to that music? To make the question more explicit, music from these websites came from peer-to-peer sharing platforms, so they likely were not acquired by paying money. That said these burned CD's from nearly 20 years ago have been recently discovered and have been sitting around gathering dust for a few decades. Is it okay for my friend to listen to these CD's or should they be thrown out or something else?

Comment: Is there a reason you believe the CDs to be generated from the websites you listed versus say just duplicated from an original CD?

Comment: I think it's unknown given how much time has passed. Assume it's 50/50.